# How to improve accuracy while reading the texts inside the rows from a tabular image PDF using tesseract?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm extracting texts from tabular image pdf using Tesseract by changing it into a sandwich pdf. For sandwich pdf, I'm using [OCRMYPDF](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF).

I'm trying with

> Ubuntu 18.04
>   tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
>   leptonica-1.75.3

Here's the link of [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e1jTWqHUUePYbbH4Ue3UfWT-gbNXtpnF/view?usp=sharing) I've tried to convert. Here's the resulting sandwich [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fk2mqKUXJ_Q0yASmNn51wsv-7PtSIM5b/view?usp=sharing).
Commands I've used to convert to sandwich pdf.

```
ocrmypdf --output-type pdf --pdf-renderer --tesseract-pagesegmode 6 sandwich test.pdf test_sw.pdf
```

The resultant accuracy of the OCRMYPDF is very poor. It cannot recognize many columns and there were a lot of spelling mistakes.

After converting into sandwich pdf, I'm using [pdftabextract](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/pdftabextract) to pull out data from the sandwich pdf.

Due to the poor accuracy cannot able to pull data from the sandwich pdf.

How to improve the accuracy of the Tesseract to OCR better in these scenarios?

Thanks in advance.